# How to find the metric tensor for a intrinsic transformation

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors, transformation

Since it is possible to map a flat plane into 3d space through:

$$X=G_X(u,v)$$
$$Y=G_Y(u,v)$$
$$Z=G_Z(u,v)$$
Then you can find the tangental basis vectors through:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial u}=\frac{\partial X}{\partial u}\frac{\partial}{\partial X}+\frac{\partial Y}{\partial u}\frac{\partial}{\partial Y}+\frac{\partial Z}{\partial u}\frac{\partial}{\partial Z}$$

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial v}=\frac{\partial X}{\partial v}\frac{\partial}{\partial X}+\frac{\partial Y}{\partial v}\frac{\partial}{\partial Y}+\frac{\partial Z}{\partial v}\frac{\partial}{\partial Z}$$

$$\hat{e_u}=\frac{\partial X}{\partial u}\hat{X}+\frac{\partial Y}{\partial u}\hat{Y}+\frac{\partial Z}{\partial u}\hat{Z}$$

$$\hat{e_v}=\frac{\partial X}{\partial v}\hat{X}+\frac{\partial Y}{\partial v}\hat{Y}+\frac{\partial Z}{\partial v}\hat{Z}$$
And then the metric through:

$$g_{ij}=e_i \cdot e_j$$

Is there a way to find the metric for a transformation that maps the 2D plane to another 2D plane
$$X = A(u,v)$$
$$Y = B(u,v)$$
Thanks

Comment: Can you please explicitly define $G_X$, etc?

Comment: @K.defaoite I was just giving an arbitrary function. The choice of function does not matter to the question. I'm just asking how do you find the metric tensor for a transformation that maps 2d -> 2d instead of 2d -> 3d

Comment: @K.defaoite For example a sphere of r = 1 would have the equation X = cos(v)sin(u) Y = sin(v)sin(u) Z = cos(u).  $g_{00} = 1$  $g_{01} = 0$  $g_{11} = \sin^2(u)$

Comment: Unfortunately I am personally only familiar with the metric tensor of dimension-preserving mappings (as these are the most relevant to mathematical physics, my area of study) so I can't help you much on this question.

Comment: @K.defaoite I know how to find the metric for a transformation for a 2d map to 3d. However, how would you find the metric for a function that maps any point in 2d to another point? Which is dimension preserving.

Comment: In this case this is just the usual metric tensor... i.e, given a coordinate mapping from the standard basis to some other basis $(x_1,x_2)\to (\xi_1,\xi_2)$ the metric tensor is
$$\mathbf{g}_{i,j}=\frac{\partial \underline{x}}{\partial \xi_i}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\frac{\partial \underline{x}}{\partial \xi_j}$$
$\underline{x}$ is the position vector.

Comment: @K.defaoite Is ξ the transformed position?

Comment: No, $\xi_i$ is the $i$th transformed coordinate.

Comment: @K.defaoite So is $\xi_0 = A(u,v)$?

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment.

Given a smooth coordinate mapping from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$, $(x_1,...,x_n)\to(\xi_1,...,\xi_n)$ which, say, could be given by some explicit transformation $\xi_i=f_i(x_1,...,x_n)$ the **metric tensor** of this transformation is defined as
$$g_{i,j}=\frac{\partial \underline{x}}{\partial\xi_i}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\frac{\partial \underline{x}}{\partial\xi_j}$$
E.g, in the case of polar coordinates in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with transformation
$$(x,y)\to\left(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta\right)$$
This is
$$\mathbf{g} =\begin{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix} & \begin{bmatrix}
0 & r
\end{bmatrix}
\end{bmatrix}$$
I've given it this flattened structure since $\mathbf{g}$ is a $(0,2)$ tensor, but it works just fine as a $2\times 2$ matrix as well.

Comment: Isn't that a coordinate transformation, not a physical one?

Comment: With the transformation, I mean the points physically move. The point (x,y) moves to the point (A(x,y), B(x,y)) when measuring with the basis vectors $\hat{e_x}$ $\hat{e_y}$. How would you find the metric for a physically distorted space?

Comment: @JoshuaPasa These are exactly the same thing. The coordinate transformation above corresponds physically to stretching the gridlines in different directions.

Comment: But doesn't the vectors stay invariant?